# I Have Scrolling In Section in UITable

Tags: iphone, uitableview

There is a table with 2 sections and each with 10 rows.

What i am trying is initially on view loading, table shows 5 rows in each section, and there is scrolling in each section individually to scroll in each section..

so not getting any idea ....

Pls help..

Thanks

Comment: [use this link][1]



or

[other link][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159821/how-do-i-scroll-a-uitableview-to-a-section-that-contains-no-rows
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359339/iphone-sdk-how-to-scroll-a-uitableview-programmatically-with-animation

Answer (score 0):

You can put a UIScrollView inside your UITableView and add subviews to it, however, the scrollView and tableView might not register your touches properly all the time.